# Rails 3.1 reCaptcha gem won't accept theme option

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, recaptcha

I'm using the recaptcha gem (github.com/ambethia/recaptcha) but have been unable to change from the default theme.  The google documentation indicates that there are four base themes, one of which is 'white'. The `recaptcha_tags` docs identify a `:display` option:

```
:display - Takes a hash containing the theme and tabindex options per the API. (default nil)
```

I'm calling the function this way:

```
 <%= recaptcha_tags :display => { :theme => "white" } %>
```

But I only get the default theme, not the white theme.  I inserted a puts() into the source of the gem where the options are parsed and get the following:

```
Options: {:public_key=>"XXXXXXXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYY", :error=>"expression"}
```

I've tried every variation I can think of to pass a `:display` option with a hash of `:theme => "white"` and can't get it to work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried and your example works for me:
`<%= recaptcha_tags :display => { :theme => "white" }%>`
My recaptcha gem version is 0.3.4, maybe you use old version?

Comment: I realized I was having some other strange things going on.  I dumped the branch I was working on and went back to the master and the problem disappeared.  Go figure.  Thanks for looking into this.